# send object inside array using Ksoap2

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

This is the code i have, which i want to sent through ksoap2. Object inside an array is creating problem for me.

```css
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:shoppingCartProductAdd soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">87a9cd5964e2dc1bf19a946a59a6175a</sessionId>
         <quoteId xsi:type="xsd:int">716</quoteId>
         <storeId xsi:type="xsd:string">1</storeId>
         <products xsi:type="urn:shoppingCartProductEntityArray" soapenc:arrayType="urn:shoppingCartProductEntity[]">
         <shoppingCartProductEntity>
         <product_id>500</product_id>
         <qty>1</qty>
         </shoppingCartProductEntity>
         </products>
      </urn:shoppingCartProductAdd>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by ignoring `<shoppingCartProductEntity>`, everything works fine for me.